# House plant growing mold -help!

Tags: houseplants, mold

I've had this house plant for almost 2 years. I don't know what it is. My husband got it from Trader Joe's as a gift for me.

[image]

I keep it by a window and it gets morning sunlight. But we live in the northeast US where winters are pretty dark. It gets whatever sunlight peaks through, but for a few months it's very sparse. I water it about once a week, a little more in the warmer months. It was originally in a smaller pot and I transplanted it about a year ago into this bigger one. Since being transplanted, it never wilted once. It got MUCH bigger. In the cold, the tips of some of the leaves browned a bit and I pruned the tips back. It has bloomed some bright red, thick pedal flowers, but probably only 4 or 5 in 2 years.

Just today I noticed gren/blue mold growing on the surface of the soil. I have not added water. The leaves filled block sun from reaching the soil. I'm not sure how to fix this! I love this pls t and don't want it to die. What can I do to save this?

[image]

Comment: some fungi is normal, and that stuff looks a lot like the stuff in miracle grow potting mix.

Comment: It wasn't there two weeks ago. I don't remember what kind of potting soil I used, but it was potted about a year ago so wouldn't it have appeared sooner?

Comment: Did you use any fertilizer recently? It looks like the Miracle Grow powder I mix into the water when I fertilize my potted plants. Do you use anything like that? Is it really as sky blue as the photo shows, or did the photo change the color of it?

Comment: The real thing looks just like the photo. I did not add anything to the soil, including fertilizer.

Answer (score 1):

Your anthurium should be OK! To ensure that the mould does not spread, remove the top level of soil. Then get the plant out of the pot and remove all other soil which goes away easily. Transplant it into new soil.
In winter water it a bit less (allow it to dry a bit between waterings) as it uses less water when it is dark.